# Transform date to wire format (YYYY-MM-DD) in javascript

Tags: javascript, date, format, momentjs

Having this input: `Wed Feb 03 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)`, is there a way to format it as YYYY-MM-DD, to it will become `2021-02-03`?

Comment: do you want to use a third party library? (like moment) You don't have to do that.

Comment: @RandyCasburn if you know a solution without moment.js, like the answer below, please let me know

Comment: If you're willing to change the accepted answer, I'll place this as an answer: `new Date('Wed Feb 04 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0200').toLocaleDateString('pl').split('.').reverse().join('-');` - you can use any locale code that transposes the day and month values.

Comment: While that looks verbose, the alternative (moment) requires importing 5500 lines of code to do this simple one-line task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
const date = moment(new Date('Wed Feb 03 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)')).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
console.log(date);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js" integrity="sha512-qTXRIMyZIFb8iQcfjXWCO8+M5Tbc38Qi5WzdPOYZHIlZpzBHG3L3by84BBBOiRGiEb7KKtAOAs5qYdUiZiQNNQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: For users with an offset less than -2, e.g. Europe/Paris, this creates a date for 2021-02-02.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing a timestamp to a date to reformat it may well produce incorrect results if the timestamp includes an offset or timezone. Given "Wed Feb 03 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)", for a user with an offset of +1 or less the date will be 2 Feb, not 3 Feb.

The most reliable method is to reformat the string, e.g.

```js
let timestamp = "Wed Feb 03 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)";

let months = [,'Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun',
               'Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];
let pad = n=>('0'+n).slice(-2);
let p = timestamp.split(' ');

console.log(`${p[3]}-${pad(months.indexOf(p[1]))}-${p[2]}`);
```